# Apache / Google undo 301 redirect

Tags: apache, seo

I did something stupid a couple of days ago :)

The was a hacker attack on a server where I had a clients website hosted.
Long story short, some files were deleted and I had to rebuild it.

In the meantime, I copied a snippet of the code I found on stackoverflow.com to redirect everybody that came to that domain to another clients domain (with another similar website).

I didn't notice that the code I copied was 301 permanent redirect...

So I'm guessing, the redirect is cached in users browsers and can't be cleared out.
But what about google?
I'm guessing google will fround upon this mistake and give the domain a penalty of some sort.. Or maybe just remove the content from the search results...

Is there a way to resolve this so google is affected as less as possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google will translate your old page rankings over to the temporary redirect because they were 301's. You can't go and tell them how to index the internet, but you can create similar 301 redirects from the temporary site to the new permanent site and that should preserve most of your Google juice.